# Container with rounded triangle/arrow in CSS

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to give the background of a container a rounded arrow feel. I want the arrow to always be stretched to full width and able to adjust height on the fly (if necessary, I can adjust height with javascript).

Here's an example:

[image]

Is this possible using CSS?

If not, how should I accomplish it -- SVG background image?

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle or a snippet including your image without the text inside?

Comment: You can add an element for just the triangle, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7r7998cp/1/). Its not rendering with exact sizes but you will get the idea. Have used `calc` here to calculate the width and height. [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility) of `calc`.

Comment: @anpsmn: I have approach working well now. How would I go about rounding the corners of the triangle using your method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements to achieve this shape.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/nym4phws/1/)

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 35px 100px;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-56deg) skewY(25deg);
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 334px;
  left: 33px;
  top: 134px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This looks great, but you're setting dimensions explicitly, so it's not going to stretch to the full width of the page. I wouldn't setting those values with javascript, but I'm not sure if I can set the pseudo element styles on the fly.